# making huffman more efficient

Tags: lua, scripting, compression, huffman-code

I currently have this Huffman algorithm in Lua

```
for _,v in next, tData do
    tFreq[v] = tFreq[v] and tFreq[v]+1 or 1
end
for k,v in next,tFreq do
    iCount = iCount + 1
    fInsert(tTree,{freq=v,contains=k})
end
while #tTree>1 do
    fSort(tTree, function(a,b)
        return a.freq<b.freq
    end)
    fInsert(tTree,{freq=tTree[1].freq+tTree[2].freq,contains={tTree[1],tTree[2]}})
    fRemove(tTree,1)
    fRemove(tTree,1)
end
iMaxSize, tKey = fSetBits(tTree[1])
```

the function fSetBits is this

```
local function fSetBits(tData, sCurrBit, sThisBit, bInternal)
    local iMaxBit, iPossBit, tSet

    sCurrBit = sCurrBit or ""
    sThisBit = sThisBit or "0"

    local tSolution = {}
    if type(tData.contains)=="table" then
        iMaxBit,tSet = fSetBits(tData.contains[1],sCurrBit..(bInternal and sThisBit or ""),1,true)
        for k,v in next,tSet  do
            tSolution[k] = v
        end
        iPossMax,tSet = fSetBits(tData.contains[2],sCurrBit..(bInternal and sThisBit or ""),0,true)
        iMaxBit = iMaxBit>iPossMax and iMaxBit or iPossMax
        for k,v in next,tSet  do
            tSolution[k] = v
        end
    else
        tSolution[tData.contains]=sCurrBit..sThisBit
        iMaxBit = #sCurrBit+1
    end
   return iMaxBit, tSolution
end
```

My biggest problem is that codes quickly become greater than 8 bits and when reading the key table I can see codes that could easily be shortened or rearranged while maintaining the no prefix rule. Is there some better way to create the bitcodes from the Huffman tree that will result in something decodable but also a lot more efficient?

Comment: All possible Huffman trees have equal efficiency with regard to compression ratio.  But they may have different tree depths.  To reduce tree depth you should take into account subtree depth while choosing two joinable subtrees in `fSort(tTree, ...)`.  Nevertheless, you should be able to work with trees of depth > 8 to make true Huffman encoder.  What the difficulties do you have while working with Huffman codes longer than 8 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code builds Huffman low-depth tree.
It is based on greedy algorithm, so I am not sure whether it always achieves best possible depth or not.

```
for _,v in next, tData do
  tFreq[v] = tFreq[v] and tFreq[v]+1 or 1
end
for k,v in next,tFreq do
  iCount = iCount + 1
  fInsert(tTree,{freq=v,contains=k,depth=0})
end
while #tTree>1 do
  fSort(tTree, function(a,b)
    return a.freq<b.freq or a.freq==b.freq and a.depth<b.depth
  end)
  fInsert(tTree,{
    freq=tTree[1].freq+tTree[2].freq,
    contains={tTree[1],tTree[2]},
    depth=math.max(tTree[1].depth,tTree[2].depth)+1})
  fRemove(tTree,1)
  fRemove(tTree,1)
end
iMaxSize, tKey = fSetBits(tTree[1])
```

Comment: Adding the depth check does indeed make many trees use shorter bit codes. Thank you very much!